# How can I get TortoiseSVN to get a list of files that are not in the repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way with TortoiseSVN to get a list of files that are not in the repository?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Right click -> TortoiseSVN -> Check For Modifications

Make sure show unversioned files is checked

Comment: I would like to add, that files, which are the same size, even modified, are rendered as not modified. Putting extra character into the file may help.

Answer (score 2):

I usually right click the root of the subversion tree and select commit. In the dialog box to select which files, it shows the files that have been added to your working copy, but haven't been added to the repository yet. Just remember not to click the ok button.

Answer (score 1):

On in any of your local project directories, you can run svn status. The equivalent in TortoiseSvn is [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html) in the manual. Items with a ? mark are unknown to the repository.